# TYPO3 11 Fluid iteration index empty by first reload after clearing system cache

Tags: iteration, typo3, fluid

I have a `for each` in Fluid, but after clearing the system cache, the iteration stays empty.
Debugging the iteration shows the result. After clearing the frontend cache, the iteration works as expected and shows the result inside the template.

For example `{iteration.cycle}` or `{iteration.index}`

Does someone know, where the problem is?

Many thank.

Comment: Have you already checked, whether the _interation_ is empty or the data to be iterated over is empty?

Comment: Both of them are filled. If I debug the iteration after clearing the system cache, I receive the values, but there are not printed inside the fluid template.

Comment: I remember having problems once where it was somehow related to `@lazy` in the model...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I have nowhere "lazy" or "@lazy" inside my extension

Comment: Pass a standard array to the template and iterate over it. Is this iteration empty as well after clearing the cache? If not, it's the data you are iterating over. What happens if you `f:debug` the data you are trying to iterate over? Is it empty?

Comment: No, the debug iteration is filled.